# Understanding mpeg-dash for VoD

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mpeg-dash

1. What programs should I use for create MPEG-DASH stream and generate manifest file [may be ffmpeg but I'm not sure that it is enough]?
2. Can I add subtitles file after I create stream?
3. Can I store audio file as another stream and attach it in manifest?